# cant migrate or work with db in laravel. how can i fix this?

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I cant migrate fresh or perform any other operation even my db is empty. It is showing following error
[image: error]

Comment: Errors clearly say about your problem. Correct your DB credentials in .env and try again.

Comment: my db credentials are ok.i get this problem even if db is empty, or even i try to wipe db

Comment: Dots could not be in table or column names.

Comment: it is automatically generated by system, database name. table name, but i am not here to access that table

Comment: do you get this error from every artisan command? such as `artisan route:list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're trying to access `site_settings` before the migrations run.

What you can do to prevent this is use `Schema::hasTable('site_settings')` in the code that is trying to access that table.

I'm assuming you're loading the site settings via a service provider or something that is trying to do things before the migrations even run.